# How to recall an attribute from a method (of parent class)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

according to codes here, I am trying to recall an attribute (branch_name) from parent class (Elec_eng) inside child class (telecoms_check method):

```
class Elec_eng:
   def __init__(self):
       print("This is Electrical Engineering main class")
   def sub_branch(self, branch_num):
       self.branch_name = branch_num

class Telecoms(Elec_eng):
   def telecoms_check(self):
       if self.branch_name == 1 :
            print("True")
       else:
            print("False")

E = Elec_eng()
T = Telecoms()
E.sub_branch(1)
```

Now, when I want to check telecoms_check method ( >> `T.telecoms_check()`  ), I expect "True" output but I got this:

```
'Telecoms' object has no attribute 'branch_name'
```

What is the problem? and How I could solve it? (with `super()` method? how?)

Comment: You didn't call `T.sub_branch` method, which explains why the *instance attribute* `branch_name` is not created.

Comment: "I expect "True" output" Why? Where are you expecting the `self.branch_name` value to have come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your useful answers.
My purpose is check an attribute value that already assigned by parent class method (I don't want to use >>> `T.sub_branch(1)` and I just Use >>> `E.sub_branch(1))`
Finally I found a solution by adding >>> `Elec_eng.branch_name = branch_num` to codes:

```
class Elec_eng:
   def __init__(self):
       print("This is Electrical Engineering main class")
   def sub_branch(self, branch_num):
       self.branch_name = branch_num
       Elec_eng.branch_name = branch_num

class Telecoms(Elec_eng):
   def telecoms_check(self):
       if self.branch_name == 1 :
            print("True")
       else:
            print("False")

E = Elec_eng()
T = Telecoms()
E.sub_branch(1)
```

Then:

```
T.telecoms_chech()
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You created two different instances, but only assigned a `branch_name` to one of them. For your code snippet to act like you are describing, you'd have to modify it to

```
>>> T = Telecoms()
>>> T.sub_branch(1)
>>> T.telecoms_check()
True
```